# Multiple Select Box in Wordpress Custom Meta Box Behaves and looks like text input

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add a select dropdown with multiple="multiple" in a custom meta box, and the select is appearing with fancy styling, is not clickable, and is not the size I am setting:

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="3" name="location">
<option value="">Please select</option>
<option value="0">All</option>
<?php
foreach(get_terms('town',array('get' => 'all')) as $term)
{
if (!empty($term->name))
{
$str .= "<option value='" . $term->term_id . "'";
$str .= (is_object_in_term($post->ID, "town", $term->name)) ? " selected>" : ">";
$str .= $term->name . "</option>";
}

} echo $str;?></select>
```

What I get is more like a text input box in appearance, although firebug shows the code is correct for a select box multiple complete with options. Any help gratefully received.

UPDATE :: ADding code of select for Bingjie's request in comments:

```
<select name="location" size="3" multiple="multiple">
                            <option value="">Please select</option>
                            <option value="0">All</option>
                            <option value="5">Akbuk</option><option value="4">Altinkum</option></select>
```

Comment: what browser are you using, can you see the source code for this part. and post it here?

Answer (score 3):

add style css.

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="3" name="location" style="height:200px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for you updates. I think the meta box is still custom meta data which is Key-value paired, so it is not allow to select multiple keys. when you retrieve post_meta, you call

```
get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single);
```

so it is not allowed to use multiple keys.
 I am not sure, but it is the only reasonable explanation since the select code appears correct.